# What would happen if I connect VLAN aware NICs via a hub?

Tags: vlan

What would happen if I connect VLAN aware NICs via a hub?
The vlan tagging is enabled and the hub here means a device that electrically connects the lines together. Would the frames with different vlan ids be dropped or would the vlan id simply be ignored when receiving?

Comment: This has been asked before. As hubs are a thing from decades past, it's anyone's guess. The hub shouldn't care what protocol is being presented, but *may* drop the slightly oversized frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More or less, a repeater hub is just a "powered wire". As such it repeats the bits from one port to the others, regardless of frame formatting, tagging, etc. Accordingly, tagged frames are forwarded unchanged across a repeater (hub).

The only active roles a hub serves are the detection and propagation of collisions, and jabber detection. Note that the latter only kills vastly oversized frames (roughly 50,000 bits per timer, there's no bit count), locking up the port.

A NIC needs to be configured for a tagged VLAN, or it'll drop/ignore those tagged frames.

Comment: Depends on the hub. Very old hubs were "simple" electrical repeaters. The last generation of hubs were very close to switches (and usually had a small switch in them to bridge 10 and 100), so they may react poorly to the extra 4 bytes in the frame. I have some Intel hubs that partition ports that send 1518 frames regularly. (it recognizes oversized frames. that's more L2 knowledge than a pseudo-wire hub would have.)

Comment: Actually, I am wondering whether the vlan aware NICs would drop the frames that don't have the same vlan id as its own.

Comment: @ZhouZhiwen The way your question was asked I assumed it was about the hub in between the hosts. Of course, a NIC drops all VLAN-tagged frames it isn't configured to.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, so VLAN division would still work when vlan aware nics are connected to a hub?

Comment: The VLAN tags pass unchanged across a hub. The VLAN separation happens inside the OS (or a switch), handling tagged frames differently. ;-)

Comment: Isn't this usually an operating system configuration feature, not a NIC feature?

Comment: @user253751 Both are possible - a "dumb" NIC passes the frame to the driver (which then might drop it or pass it to the OS stack), a VLAN-capable NIC might drop an unknown VLAN right away.

Comment: That‘s very clear, Thx!